# How to install Windows Service from C# code (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have a Windows service developed in C# and I would like to install this service from a Winforms application in C# but not in a DOS command:

```
installutil \i ..
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Installing a Windows Service requires admin privileges so the winforms app would need to be running with elevated privileges. If this is ok, then you could use `Process.Start` to invoke the `installutil.exe`. `Process.Start` also allows you to pass in a username and password so that is another option if the winforms app does not have elevated permissions.

Have a look at this article which has more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx